# How to get average value from SQL(Superset, SQLAlchemy under PostgreSQL) timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I tried to calculate the average timestamp and the query is successfully executed directly in postgresql, but when executed through superset(python's SQLAlchemy), an error occurs when converting an integer to a timestamp. How can I fix the error or do it in another way?

### Query1:

```
select 
    to_timestamp(
        avg(
            cast(
                extract(epoch from last_checked_at) as integer)
                )::integer
        ) as datetime
from
    the_best_table
```

**Query1 postgresql result:**

| datetime |
| --- |
| 2022-02-06 03:15:19+00 |

**Query1 superset(SQLAlchemy) result:**

> PostgreSQL Error postgresql error: '>=' not supported between
> instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
>
> This may be triggered by: Issue 1002 - The database returned an
> unexpected error. [link](https://superset.apache.org/docs/miscellaneous/issue-codes/#issue-1002)

Also below you can see the results of the query to convert an integer to datetime. The problem is in this part of the code.

### Query2:

```
select to_timestamp(1644117319) as datetime
```

**Query2 postgresql result:**

| datetime |
| --- |
| 2022-02-06 03:15:19+00 |

**Query2 superset(SQLAlchemy) result:**

> PostgreSQL Error postgresql error: '>=' not supported between
> instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
>
> This may be triggered by: Issue 1002 - The database returned an
> unexpected error. [link](https://superset.apache.org/docs/miscellaneous/issue-codes/#issue-1002)

Comment: Those are python errors. Can you please share the python code that includes this query?

Comment: Please also [edit] the question to include any tracebacks generated in the Python layer, and any relevant logging (for example, queries generated by SQLAlchemy if SQLAlchemy logging is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the error.
Works fine.

Setup in Postgresql Database:

```
postgres=> create table the_best_table(last_checked_at timestamp);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> insert into the_best_table values(now());
INSERT 0 1
postgres=> select
    to_timestamp(
        avg(
            cast(
                extract(epoch from last_checked_at) as integer)
                )::integer
        ) as datetime
from
    the_best_table;
        datetime
------------------------
 2022-02-07 04:54:06+09
(1 row)
```

The exact two queries run fine for me in SQLAlchemy:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://<username>:<passwd>@192.xxx.xxx.123/postgres')
>>>  metadata.create_all(engine)
>>> with engine.connect() as con:
...     rs = con.execute('select to_timestamp(avg(cast(extract(epoch from last_checked_at) as integer))::integer ) as datetime from the_best_table;')
...     for row in rs:
...             print(row)
... 
(datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 4, 54, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=32400))),)
>>> with engine.connect() as con:
...     rs = con.execute('select to_timestamp(1644117319) as datetime;')
...     for row in rs:
...             print(row)
... 
(datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 6, 12, 15, 19, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=32400))),)
```